# heroku app not being properly updated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I'm new to the web development scene, so sorry if my lack of knowledge bugs you

When i run my local code using rails s and testing on my own server, the front end is not the same as the local one.

My first attempt was to initially fix some snippet of code, then use git push, then git push heroku master.

I've tried deleting the app and pushing fresh new code again, and it still doesn't work

I've tried heroku restart, and no changes also

Any suggestions?

*edit*

*pictures for clarity*

*top is local, bottom is heroku server*

[image: Local one]

[image: heroku one]

Comment: What do you mean by " the front end is not the same as the local one" - how is it not the same? What's the problem?

Comment: colors, some font-awesome icons missing from footer, some things are not sized properly, that kind of stuff.

Comment: So your CSS is not there?

Comment: yeah, if you look at the pictures, the jumbotron on local is much bigger because of the CSS file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to `@RSB`'s comment, you'll probably find that your CSS is not being compiled properly

To fix this, you'll have to perform a precompile when you deploy. However, [Heroku already does this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline), so probably won't be an issue

---

The best thing to do is eliminate any potential issues -

1. `#config/environments/production.rb` - `config.serve_static_assets = true`
2. local - `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`
3. `git add .`
4. `git commit -a -m "CSS Test"`
5. `git push heroku master`

Comment: thanks! this fixed it! are you saying that every time i fix some frontend work i have to precompile and then push?

Comment: It's best to, yes. Reason is because it gives you a local set of CSS which you then just send to Heroku

Answer (score 1):

Try running this command in your project folder

```
heroku run rake assets:precompile
```